# How to update PHP version from 5.4.16 to 5.6.20 or a newer version in Wordpress

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I have a Centos 7.7. server where I am hosting my website. I tried to update the PHP version from the CLI but nothing has changed on Wordpress:

> "You cannot update because WordPress 5.2.4 requires PHP version 5.6.20 or higher. You are running version 5.4.16."

```
# php -v
PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2019 09:27:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

# rpm -qa|grep php
rh-php71-php-json-7.1.30-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-cli-7.1.30-1.el7.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
php-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
php-mysql-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-7.1.30-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-zip-7.1.30-1.el7.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
rh-php71-runtime-1-1.el7.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
php-xmlrpc-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-common-7.1.30-1.el7.x86_64
php-pdo-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
php-xml-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
```

# httpd -M
[Fri Nov 15 13:57:00.257580 2019] [so:warn] [pid 14807] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 ldap_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)

[image]

I don't have cPanel and I need to find a way to update directly from the server.
Also I'm using Apache and is not a shared hosting.
Thanks.

Comment: are you on shared hosting or VPS? Are you using apache or ngix? You need to update with more information

Comment: Hi Stefano, I am using Apache and is the only webserver hosted on my server ( is not a shared hosting). Thank you

Comment: can you post result of `sudo httpd -M`?

Comment: You need to be sure that the cli version and the one Apache is using are the same

Comment: You might want to cross check with this link just to make sure that you correctly installed the combo: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php/

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo i just edited with the output of the httpd -M command.

Comment: Hi @StefanoMtangoo, the apache PHP version is 5.4.16 (from info.php under /var/www/http/) and PHP cli version is 7.1 (output from php -v). Thanks

Comment: sorry for late reply. I was carried off by many other things. Glad you resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my issue, I renamed the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/10-php.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/10-php.conf.off and I copied /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/rh-php71-php.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/. and restarted the https service. 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

The php version running on the server itself is (and can be) different than the php version running with apache. You need to enable the php version for your apache server with

```
sudo a2dismod php5.4
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

(Google for it)

With the `php -v` command you get not the php version of the apache server.

Btw php 7.3 is the actual version. If you already updating stuff, try to enable the HTTP2 protocol and install php-fpm instead of cli.

**Edit:**
a2enmod does not work with Centos, this is debianism. You need to enable the php version in the *.conf files and restart apache.

Comment: The output of php -v 

# php -v
PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2019 09:27:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

I follow the steps given by @Stefano, i created a file with info.php, restarted the httpd and when i run in browser it shows me PHP Version 5.4.16

Comment: PS: a2dismod  and a2enmod  are not for centOS distribution, just Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, really? I was not aware of that. Nonetheless, you need to enable the php version for your apache server and php -v shows you the default php version of your system. If a2enmod does not work, then you have to do it manually in the *.conf file.